# Why is day of pandas date_range not what I specified?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, date-range

Why is the first date not 4/19/1965? Why day 30 instead of 19?

```
dates = pd.date_range('1965-04-19', freq='6M', periods=3)
dates[0]

Timestamp('1965-04-30 00:00:00', offset='6M')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the default behavior for `freq='M'` is `MonthEnd()`, so

```
dates = pd.date_range('1965-04-19', periods=3, freq='6M')
dates

DatetimeIndex(['1965-04-30', '1965-10-31', '1966-04-30'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='6M', tz=None)
```

This can be changed by setting `freq = pd.tseries.offsets.DateOffset(months=6)`.

```
dates = pd.date_range('1965-04-19', periods=3, freq=pd.tseries.offsets.DateOffset(months=6))
dates

DatetimeIndex(['1965-04-19', '1965-10-19', '1966-04-19'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='<DateOffset: kwds={'months': 6}>', tz=None)
```